# Mining using Four computers.... what to do?

Tags: mining

I've been reading through the page for ideas but thought I'd just ask.

I have 4 basic desktop computers that I are only used for a few hours a week.

The graphics is integrated with the CPU so I know I have to buy graphics cards which isn't a problem. 
I have been reading about the Radeon RX480, but have also notice people using 2xRadeon RX260. I just wanted to get peoples opinions on whats best.

Thanks

Eddue

Comment: Please specify _"What to do?"_, Stack Exchange is not the best place to ask about product recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

As I know best graphic cards for mining are RX 470, RX 480, RX 570, RX 580.
Two days ago I have ordered 4x RX 580 4GB and each of them will provide approximately 27MH/s and I strongly advise you to buy them.